# Exception on Fetch/Clone/Pull with custom transport

Tags: libgit2sharp

I wrote a custom smarttransport. After fetch, pull or clone I get valid data but the method throws LibGit2Sharp Exception with "error reading from the zlib stream".

Transport with upload-pack read->write->read->write works.

READ:

> 00fc5daa747d4ca7905ff8996f770ef74d1b894be3d2 HEAD multi_ack thin-pack
>   side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not
>   deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed
>   symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.18.0.windows.1
>   003f5daa747d4ca7905ff8996f770ef74d1b894be3d2 refs/heads/master
>   003e5daa747d4ca7905ff8996f770ef74d1b894be3d2 refs/heads/test2 0000

WRITE:

> 0074want 5daa747d4ca7905ff8996f770ef74d1b894be3d2
>   multi_ack_detailed side-band-64k include-tag thin-pack ofs-delta
>   0032want 5daa747d4ca7905ff8996f770ef74d1b894be3d2 00000009done

READ:

> 0008NAK 0023Enumerating objects: 9, done. Counting objects: 100%
>   (9/9), done. Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done. 002bTotal 9
>   (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 02e7PACK              òx£ì-1-0
>   +=»+ÄälºNc  !6Ìß$NAé+­x-m763[AÁ+sª$C+!7eì[å$í¦Àn÷^A&ã:Cÿ+-T#&Ö+BfàªäëKê+Úg_·µ»}+²i¨yi·¦Ò+ï«gÅÉä+Ç
>   \Ú¤þ}¹©]ks_.k8¬òx£ì-=-0@ß=º+ÄäþºÄäþpº
>   ZéZszûÀ}z¦ëÏ\KpêÈUqòÉk+=-Ç U8O
>   àú¨­&oÁëÿ=ó`ª=d+AÊ4qóÏÇ:+ã-áß»>ãf´cÌÝe>zÙ³Æ¾2*/WÙó?«ô-hOÇ
>   ªÄu}¬- -¿ýj~Ç@9[ÿ
>
>   x£ì-1-0@Ð=º­ÄäLLöTBê¡þpmÀDñDj-²¦#¦³7}¯¦@°nël8eÔR-ª¿ëSûY'UM%IÓƒ+¹c_vx,g_3ý+¦p{--ûé4d©`DÊÎÁ¦¦ G¿¯Ûò[8
>   Ë-õ¿x£343
>   ¢Éd¸¦åîUFzÜ--£+²Ê½2.Þr³ê]Ùdh`fbóPöÜÿÆø¬WRQ-ã»Ã¤J¦_Ðß¾ØKMº¥à
>   3Sã¦x£-¦-,+L¦QH+¤--,I,NIa.-à-3©îí+  §Ó-¿x£343
>   ¢Éd¸¦åîUFzÜ--£+²Ê½2.Þr³ê]Ùdh`fbóPöÜÿÆø¬WRQ-­=âìBnï§+=ƒ º=¦|[c
>   N+ô¦x£-¦-,+L¦QH+¤--,I,NIa.-ò
>   +®*ªx£340031Q(JML+Mi+®(a+§u¦sQ?-§î¦O´¢¹¦,²Û+.  H>x£-¦-,+L¦QH+¤--, )-öP¸ãyô

WRITE:

> 0000

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException'
>   occurred in LibGit2Sharp.dll
>
> Additional information: error reading from the zlib stream

Callstack:

> bei LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) in
>   C:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:Zeile 136.    bei
>   LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_fetch(RemoteHandle remote,
>   IEnumerable`1 refSpecs, GitFetchOptions fetchOptions, String
>   logMessage) in
>   C:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:Zeile 2268.    bei
>   LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Fetch(Repository repository, String remote,
>   IEnumerable`1 refspecs, FetchOptions options, String logMessage) in
>   C:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Commands\Fetch.cs:Zeile 76.
>   bei GitFunction.Test.Beta2.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in
>   C:\TFS\DS\ThomasZ\BeckhoffGitAdsService\GitAdsServicePackage\GitFunction.Test\Beta2.cs:Zeile
>   62.    bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)    bei
>   GitFunction.Test.Program.Main() in
>   C:\TFS\DS\ThomasZ\BeckhoffGitAdsService\GitAdsServicePackage\GitFunction.Test\Program.cs:Zeile
>   19.    bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)    bei
>   System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)    bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    bei
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Versions:

- git version 2.18.0.windows.1
- Win 10 x64
- LibGit2Sharp 0.24.0.0
- LibGit2Sharp 0.25.0.0

Comment: error message: "error reading from the zlib stream" occurs in libgit2 within pack.c in method git_packfile_stream_read() after calling inflate(&obj->zstream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH); Error will be called if the result is !=Z_OK && !=Z_STREAM_END

Comment: After setting pack.compression=0 the zlib stream contains uncompressed data. But the error message is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:
UTF8Encoding and Encoding.Utf8 are not equal. Encoding.Utf8 adds UTF8 BOM (Byte-order Mark). This leads to this error. Setting all encodings to UTF8Encoding in my code fixed my problem.